# Intermittent exception in tests using the java Kafka client

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am testing two classes intended to write and read from Kafka (v0.10.1) logs using the official Java client and an embedded server. I get the following intermittent exception trace when instantiating one of the consumers:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:702)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:557)
    at cakesolutions.kafka.KafkaConsumer$.apply(KafkaConsumer.scala:128)
    at com.jobandtalent.kafka.client.KafkaTopic.com$jobandtalent$kafka$client$KafkaTopic$$buildConsumer$1(KafkaTopic.scala:37)
    at com.jobandtalent.kafka.client.KafkaTopic$$anonfun$initialize$1$1.apply(KafkaTopic.scala:30)
    at com.jobandtalent.kafka.client.KafkaTopic$$anonfun$initialize$1$1.apply(KafkaTopic.scala:29)
    at fs2.Task$$anonfun$delay$1.apply(Task.scala:187)
    at fs2.Task$$anonfun$delay$1.apply(Task.scala:187)
    at fs2.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1$$anonfun$2.apply(Task.scala:195)
    at fs2.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1$$anonfun$2.apply(Task.scala:195)
    at fs2.util.Attempt$.apply(Attempt.scala:12)
    at fs2.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1.apply(Task.scala:195)
    at fs2.Task$$anonfun$suspend$1.apply(Task.scala:195)
    at fs2.internal.Future.step(Future.scala:54)
    at fs2.internal.Future.listen(Future.scala:30)
    at fs2.internal.Future.runAsync(Future.scala:69)
    at fs2.Task.unsafeRunAsync(Task.scala:96)
    at fs2.Task$Ref$$anonfun$set$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(Task.scala:332)
    at fs2.Strategy$$anon$3$$anon$4.run(Strategy.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:332)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:637)
    ... 23 more
```

During `KafkaConsumer` initialization, a `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor` is instantiated correctly but the downcast to `PartitionAssignor` fails. This is the line failing:

```
List<PartitionAssignor> assignors = config.getConfiguredInstances(
       ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,
       PartitionAssignor.class);
```

How can this be happening?

Comment: can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the root cause of the exception but I fixed it by manually setting the context classloader before instantiating the Kafka client.

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(...any class from the Kafka jar...)
```

Comment: it must be class conflicts. maybe embedded server introduced some legacy classes.

Comment: how to load any class from kafka jar?